# Populate input field when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to click on the links to populate  the input field, because of the "p class="tag""  been nested in all those "div" tags I can get it to work. Ant idea how I can do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('p.tag').live('click', function(e){
$('#tag').val(this.innerHTML);
return false;  
});
```

```
<html>
<tr>
<td align="left" width="100%" colspan="0">&nbsp;
<div class="my_list">
<div class="list">
<div id="list-wrapper">
<p class="tag">&nbsp;&nbsp;Name 1</p>
<p class="tag">&nbsp;&nbsp;Name 2</p>
<p class="tag">&nbsp;&nbsp;Name 3</p>
<p class="tag">&nbsp;&nbsp;Name 4</p>
  <p class="tag">&nbsp;&nbsp;Name 5</p>   
</div>
</div>
<div class="showme">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="color" href='' title='Show App' name="all">
 Show 
</a>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input id="tag" type="text" name="name" value=""></td>
</tr>

</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: `.live` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid, you need to wrap your code inside `<table>` since `<tr>` and `<td>` must stay inside a `<table>`

Secondly, you should use **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead of `.live()` because from the **[upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed)**:

> The .live() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and has been
>   removed in 1.9. We recommend upgrading code to use the .on() method
>   instead.

```
$('p.tag').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#tag').val(this.innerHTML);
    return false;
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9r46W/)**

---

If your paragraphs have been added dynamically, then you can use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**:

```
$('body').on("click", "p.tag", function(){
    $('#tag').val(this.innerHTML);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I think it should be `$(document).on("click", "p.tag", function(){...});` since he used `.live`.

Comment: No need to use event delegation here since his elements is not dynamically generated.

Comment: Thank you, this worked: <script type="text/javascript">
 
    \$(document).on("click", "p.tag", function(){
    \$('#tag').val(this.innerHTML);
    return false;
    });

  </script>

Comment: OK, I had to change  the $(document).on("click", TO $(document).on("click touchstart". Solved!